# Javascript array indexed by strings can't be converted to JSON using JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been trying to stringify a javascript array which is keyed by strings. JSON always stringifies the array as empty (`[]`).

```
var arr = new Array(3);
arr['A'] = "Foo";
arr['B'] = "Bar";
arr['C'] = "Baz";

var str = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

If I replace the 'A', 'B', 'C' with 0,1,2 then the array is stringified correctly. I'm sure I'm missing something, just not sure what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant have keys as strings in array, use object for this {}.

```
var obj = {};
obj['A'] = "Foo";
obj['B'] = "Bar";
obj['C'] = "Baz";

var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an Object, not an Array.

```
JSON.stringify({
  "A": "Foo",
  "B": "Bar",
  "C": "Baz"
});
```